# Page Scrolling Issue When Multiple Chart on Same Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am facing some problems when I scroll a page that contains multiple charts. I have 5 charts that exist below one after one, and I set my scrolling behavior by SingleChildScrollView. When I go to view charts by scrolling the page, some charts have not stayed on the center point of the page. Automatically the goes to the invisible area.

[image: Flutter Chart Scrolling]

My Widgets Hierarchy is -
RefreshIndicator -> Column -> Expanded -> Container -> Container -> ScrollConfiguration -> SingleChildScrollView -> Container -> Column -> Column -> Container -> AspectRatio -> Container -> Stack -> Column -> Expanded -> Padding -> SfCartesianChart

```
ScrollConfiguration(
                behavior: const ScrollBehavior(),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Container(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        reportCart(
                            title: 'Average Monthly Income',
                            subTitle:
                                '\$${provider.viewData.averageMonthlyIncome.floor()}',
                            subTitleStyle: Styles.subHeadingTextStyle2,
                            icon: CupertinoIcons.tag),
                        reportCart(
                            title: 'Average Monthly Growth',
                            subTitle:
                                '${provider.viewData.averageMonthlyGrowth.toStringAsFixed(2)}%',
                            subTitleStyle: Styles.subHeadingTextStyle2,
                            icon: Icons.archive_outlined),
                        reportCart(
                            title: 'YTD Profit',
                            subTitle: '\$${provider.viewData.ytdProfit.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                            subTitleStyle: Styles.subHeadingTextStyle2,
                            icon: Icons.copy),
                        reportCart(
                            title: 'Loan Balance',
                            subTitle: '\$ ${provider.viewData.loanBalance.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                            subTitleStyle: Styles.subHeadingTextStyle2Red,
                            icon: Icons.archive_outlined),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Income By Month',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/1.5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
                                ),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: IncomeByMonthChart(incomeByMonth: provider.viewData.incomeByMonth,),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        /// Chart : Loan By Month
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Loan By Month',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/1.5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
                                ),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: LoanByMonthChart(loanByMonth: provider.viewData.loanByMonth,),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        /// Chart : Income Vs Expense
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Income Vs Expense',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/1.8,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: SfCartesianChart(
                                              zoomPanBehavior: _zoomPanBehavior,
                                              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true, color: MyColors.primaryColorLight),
                                              series: <ChartSeries>[
                                                ColumnSeries<IncomeVsExpense, String>(
                                                  name: 'Income',
                                                  dataSource: provider.viewData.incomeVsExpense,
                                                  xValueMapper: (IncomeVsExpense data, _)=>data.month,
                                                  yValueMapper: (IncomeVsExpense data, _) => data.income,

                                                  enableTooltip: true,
                                                  dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false, labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside),
                                                ),
                                                ColumnSeries<IncomeVsExpense, String>(
                                                  name: 'Expense',
                                                  dataSource: provider.viewData.incomeVsExpense,
                                                  xValueMapper: (IncomeVsExpense data, _)=>data.month,
                                                  yValueMapper: (IncomeVsExpense data, _) => data.expense,
                                                  enableTooltip: true,
                                                  dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false, labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                                              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                                edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
                                                numberFormat: NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(decimalDigits: 0),),
                                             /* primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                                title: AxisTitle(
                                                  text: 'Amount',
                                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                                    fontSize: 11,
                                                    fontFamily: MyFont.poppins,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ),*/

                                              legend: Legend(isVisible: true, position: LegendPosition.top,),

                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        /// Chart: Income Expense Breakdown
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Income Expense Breakdown',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/2.5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: SfCartesianChart(
                                              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true, color: MyColors.primaryColorLight),
                                              plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                                              series: <ChartSeries<_ChartSampleData, String>>[
                                                WaterfallSeries<_ChartSampleData, String>(
                                                    negativePointsColor: const Color(0xffff0000),
                                                    intermediateSumColor: const Color(
                                                        0xff00ff00),
                                                    totalSumColor: const Color(
                                                        0xff007800),
                                                  dataSource: <_ChartSampleData>[
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'Income',
                                                        y: 1146000,
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: false,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: false),
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'COSG',
                                                        y: -346500,
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: false,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: false),
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'Gross Profit',
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: true,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: false),
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'Operating',
                                                        y: -275500,
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: false,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: false),
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'Non-Operating',
                                                        y: -216500,
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: false,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: false),
                                                    _ChartSampleData(
                                                        x: 'Net Profit',
                                                        intermediateSumPredicate: false,
                                                        totalSumPredicate: true),
                                                  ],

                                                  xValueMapper: (_ChartSampleData data, _)=>data.x,
                                                  yValueMapper: (_ChartSampleData data, _) => data.y,
                                                  intermediateSumPredicate: (_ChartSampleData data, _) => data.intermediateSumPredicate,
                                                  totalSumPredicate: (_ChartSampleData data, _) => data.totalSumPredicate,

                                                  enableTooltip: true,
                                                  dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true,),
                                                ),

                                              ],
                                              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                                                  majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                                                  labelIntersectAction: false
                                                      ? AxisLabelIntersectAction.wrap
                                                      : AxisLabelIntersectAction.rotate45),
                                              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                                  name: 'Expenditure',
                                                  minimum: 0,
                                                  maximum: 1400000,
                                                  axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
                                                  majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(size: 0),
                                                  axisLabelFormatter: (AxisLabelRenderDetails details) {
                                                    return ChartAxisLabel(
                                                        (details.value ~/ 1000).toString() + 'B', null);
                                                  }),
                                              /* primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                                title: AxisTitle(
                                                  text: 'Amount',
                                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                                    fontSize: 11,
                                                    fontFamily: MyFont.poppins,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ),*/

                                              legend: Legend(isVisible: true, position: LegendPosition.top,),

                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        /// Chart : Income By Customer
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Income By Customer',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/1.5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: SfCartesianChart(
                                              zoomPanBehavior: _zoomPanBehavior,
                                              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true, color: MyColors.primaryColorLight),
                                              series: <ChartSeries>[
                                                BarSeries<IncomeByCustomer, String>(
                                                    name: 'Income',
                                                    dataSource: provider.viewData.incomeByCustomer,
                                                    xValueMapper: (IncomeByCustomer data, _)=>data.customerCode,
                                                    yValueMapper: (IncomeByCustomer data, _) => data.income,
                                                enableTooltip: true,
                                                dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true, labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside),)
                                              ],
                                              legend: Legend(isVisible: false, position: LegendPosition.top,),
                                              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                                              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                                edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
                                              numberFormat: NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(decimalDigits: 0),),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        /// Chart :  Profit % By Customer
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 0, right:10, bottom: 10,),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Profit % By Customer',
                                style: Styles.headlineTextStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 2/1.5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children:  <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 0),
                                            child: SfCircularChart(
                                              tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true, color: MyColors.primaryColorLight),
                                              onTooltipRender: (TooltipArgs tooltip){
                                                int? index = tooltip.pointIndex?.toInt();

                                                if(index != null){

                                                  tooltip.text = '${tooltip.dataPoints![index].x} : \$${tooltip.dataPoints![index].y}';
                                                }
                                              },

                                              onDataLabelRender: (dataLabel){
                                                int? index = dataLabel.pointIndex?.toInt();
                                                if(index != null){
                                                  double totalIncome = provider.viewData.totalIncomeByCustomer;
                                                  double perPercent = totalIncome / 100;
                                                  double percent = dataLabel.dataPoints[index].y / perPercent;
                                                  dataLabel.text = '${dataLabel.dataPoints![index].x} : ${percent.toStringAsFixed(2)} %,';
                                                }
                                              },
                                              series: <CircularSeries>[
                                                DoughnutSeries<IncomeByCustomer, String>(
                                                  dataSource: provider.viewData.incomeByCustomer,
                                                  xValueMapper: (IncomeByCustomer data, _)=>data.customerCode,
                                                  yValueMapper: (IncomeByCustomer data, _) => data.income,
                                                  enableTooltip: true,
                                                  dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true, labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside),
                                                  )
                                              ],
                                              legend: Legend(isVisible: true, position: LegendPosition.bottom,),

                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Yes, I added my code snippet in my question.

Comment: Can you include package name and about `reportCart`

Comment: I am using 'syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.4.54' in my project.